# Does the shape of a supernova remnant depend on the progenitor star's magnetic field?

Tags: star, supernova, magnetic-field

The magnetic field activity in a star can be very chaotic and my question is are they somehow related?

Comment: @ Rob Jeffries actually I wanted to state nebula instead of supernova I wanted to know why there are so many different shapes of nebulae but first it must take form at time of explosion maybe.

Comment: Could you show some example pictures or links to example pictures in your question?

Comment: I don't want to give this as an answer, cause I'm not 100% sure, but the shape of a nebula may have as much to do with the gas that the matter expelled from the star bumps into as it does with the explosion itself.   I don't know how much effect magnetism has on any non uniformity of the explosion, so I can't say for sure, but I think the gas surrounding the nova is the larger factor.

Answer (score 1):

The factors that affect the shape of supernova remnants include:

1. Interstellar medium (the gas and particles between stars)
2. Planets that surrounded the star
3. **Magnetic field** (in the same way magnetic fields cause auroras)
4. Mass distribution of the star before supernova

There are probably more, but that's all I can think of at the moment

Comment: While not technically affecting the shape, the orientation of the supernova remnant will affect how it appears from our vantage point on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the shape of the supernova remnant is mainly caused by the structure and biometry of the star. At the time of explosion the layers of the star expands
and high speeds which result in a supernova remnant. A good example is the crab nebula in constellation Taurus.